# Vue type script - data and custom types

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types, nuxt.js

I have a type called student.

```
export interface Student {
  name: string,
  age: number
}
```

I want to assign that type to data to a student.

```
data() {
const tommy: Student = {}
return {
  tommy,
```

}

However when I assign a string to that data in the mounted hook  I get no warnings or issues.

```
  async mounted() {
    this.tommy= 'Tommy Smith'
```

How should I define custom data types in vue typescript.

Comment: That makes sense. You lose the type inference when you assign the value of `tommy` to the object its self. Vue doesn't understand this. Instead, you need to define the properties of your component, which `tommy` will now be a property.

Answer (score 1):

You could either choose to use the Composition API where you can instantiate an Object with a certain class the way you did:
const tommy: Student;

or if you want to continue using the Options API you could use type assertions like this:

```
data() {
    return {
      tommy: {name: '', age: 0} as Student
    }
}
```

problem furthermore: you assigned a string to tommy, instead you should assign the string to the name property:

```
  async mounted() {
    this.tommy.name = 'Tommy Smith'
```